# How to Add New Image Field in Create Product Attribute Form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

How to Add New Image Field in Create Product Attribute Form in Magento 2.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to create InstallSchema.php on location vendor\Module\Setup

> ```
> public function install(
>         ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
>         ModuleContextInterface $context
>     ) {
>         /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
>         $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
>         $setup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);         
>         $setup->addAttribute(
>             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'custom_image', [
>                 'type' => 'varchar',
>                 'label' => 'Custom Image',
>                 'input' => 'image',
>                 'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
>                 'required' => false,
>                 'sort_order' => 9,
>                 'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
>                 'group' => 'General Information',
>             ]
>         );
>     }
> ```

2. Create a category_form.xml file on location vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component

`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="content">
    <field name="custom_image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="module/category_image/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset> </form>`

3. Add code in vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

> Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload
>
>
>
>
> catalog/tmp/category
> catalog/category
>
> jpg
> jpeg
> gif
> png

4. Create UploadImage.php file on location with execute function() Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image

With try catch block

```
$result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('custom_image');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
```

1. At last create data provider on Vendor\Module\Model\Category

> class DataProvider extends
> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider {
>
> ```
> protected function getFieldsMap()
> {
>     $fields = parent::getFieldsMap();
>     $fields['content'][] = 'custom_image'; // custom image field
>     
>     return $fields;
> } }
> ```

Comment: It works for me, hope this might be helpful, Please accept if so.

Comment: I need to create an attribute in the Store >> Product tab when creating a new product attribute.  

You have provided in category attribute for the category page.